# Would Like to Know how Instead of UPDATE Trigger with Inner join on inserted Table Works

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is a trigger on an update sets the UPDATE_TS to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
The trigger works successfully, but I would like to know how it works. My understanding is that the inserted table contains all records inserted.

My questions:
1) I do not understand how the inner join that I am using here knows to select the items that are being inserted?
What items are contained in the inserted table at the moment this trigger is in execution,

2) how can I see the contents of the inserted table at the moment of execution?

3) And what table am I doing an inner join on inserted table with?

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_update_ts_trigger
ON [mydatabase].dbo.[MY_TABLE]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE t SET
      ANOTHER_TABLE_ID = i.ANOTHER_TABLE_ID,
      FREE_TEXT= i.FREE_TEXT,
      UPDATE_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      CREATE_USER = i.CREATE_USER,
      UPDATE_USER = i.UPDATE_USER
    FROM [dbo].MY_TABLE AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON t.MY_TABLE_ID = i.MY_TABLE_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is quite straightforward:

Sql Server populates inserted and deleted temporary tables in tempdb with rows that are 'touched' by the statement. Those tables have the same structure as the original table.

- In a trigger FOR **INSERT**, you have all new records in **inserted** table
- In a trigger FOR **DELETE**, you have all deleted records in **deleted**
  table
- In a trigger FOR **UPDATE**, ou have both: old records in **deleted**
  (old values), new records in **inserted** (new values).

When you join your table with inserted or deleted, you should do the join on the pk fields (MY_TABLE_ID in your example), but you can use any other columns if you have to update another table.

The important thing to remember is that there are several records in those inserted and deleted pseudo tables : all records modified (inserted, deleted or updated) by your statement. 
For example if you do a simple (silly example just for the explanation):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = MyField
```

without any **WHERE** clause, you are updating all records in your table and the whole table will be copied to inserted and deleted tables and accessible to your trigger.

see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

inserted and deleted are virtual tables managed by Sql, you don't have access to them.

Note also that since you are using an **INSTEAD OF** trigger, Sql will not update any rows but instead of executing the initial UPDATE statement, Sql will run the code of your trigger, so you have to do the UPDATE in your trigger, and you could update a different table instead of the original one.

If you were using an AFTER trigger, Sql would have done the initial update, then called your trigger code

Comment: Does this mean that after the trigger is run those lines representing records "touched" by the update statement are removed from the insert/delete tables?

Comment: yes they are internal temporary tables, you don't have access to them